# Clone a Set including real type

Tags: java

Is it possible to implement this method ?

```
public <T> Set<T> cloneSet(Set<T> original);
```

The resulting Set **must** be of the same type as the original Set (example, if original is a TreeSet, then the resulting Set is also a TreeSet.

Comment: perhaps call `clone` on the set?

Comment: If you limit yourself to the implementations from the standard Java libraries, then I think they all have a `clone` method.

Comment: @john16384 that's what i thought at first, but Set is not Cloneable

Comment: You could cast the set to `Cloneable` first, but it won't work for all sets.

Comment: @john16384 there is a compilation error if i try to do that

Comment: Hm, never mind, I remember now that `Cloneable` does not actually define the clone method, it is a protected method on `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection for this. See this example:

```
public class CloneTest {

    public static <T> Set<T> clone(Set<T> set) {
        try {
            Set<T> cloned = set.getClass().newInstance();
            cloned.addAll(set);
            return cloned;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> test = new TreeSet<>();
        test.add("asd");
        printClone(clone(test));
        printClone(clone(new HashSet<>(test)));
    }

    public static void printClone(Set<?> set) {
        System.out.println(set.getClass().getSimpleName());
        set.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

This will print:

```
TreeSet
asd
HashSet
asd
```

It uses the class information to just create a new instance. Given that we know it is a set, we can then call addAll to add all the elements. The elements are not cloned though, so they are the same reference.

This works because there is a default constructor on the sets. I believe if you had a non-empty constructor, the `newInstance` method would likely fail.

This was a fun little example, but I would not use that in production :)

Artur

Comment: This will fail to return a "clone" even for a TreeSet containing instances of a non-comparable type - ie you created the TreeSet using a ctor taking a Comparator.